# Encrypted the file from S3 side. Need to decrypt the file from EFS side

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-kms

Hi I have a file that upload on AWS S3 bucket where we enable KMS encryption . With AWS Datasync we will be transfering my file from s3 to EFS. How we can decrypt the file.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not have to do anything. AWS will decrypt the S3 file automatically whenever you read it if you are using encryption at rest.

Comment: We are using yml file which is situated in EFS mount point for accessing the file we are not using EC2 just we are using S3 to EFS transfer the file to run it on ECS cluster.

Comment: @vikashsharma It does not matter. AWS decrypts file automatically.